# MySQL ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY error what if you want to select lot of columns or you want to do SELECT *

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I just upgraded Ubuntu to the latest version which upgraded MySQL to the latest version. Some of my queries like the one below fail with the expected error below:

> Query:

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(date) as thedate, ANY_VALUE(name), ordersetid, price  FROM orders LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses ON orders.addressid = addresses.id WHERE orders.owner =  'admin' GROUP BY ordersetid order by thedate DESC
```

> Error:

```
#1055 - Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mydb.orders.price' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

I understand the way to solve this problem is to use aggregate functions or ANY_VALUE keyword on the fields to select as below

> Working Query:

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(date) as thedate, ANY_VALUE(name), ordersetid, ANY_VALUE(price)  FROM orders LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses ON orders.addressid = addresses.id WHERE orders.owner =  'admin' GROUP BY ordersetid order by thedate DESC
```

My question is, what if I am having a lot of columns or I want to select all the columns. Is there another way of doing this?

Note: I understand how to disable full_groupby_by settings in MySQL but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you have lot of columns then what about the following idea:

**First step:** You create a stored procedure that can execute a prepared statement generated from an input query string.

**Second step:** You create another stored procedure that generate the desired query string. That is based on `information_schema` query the columns that you need to put into the `ANY_VALUE()` statement from your desired database and tables and call the previous stored procedure in order to execute it and get the desired results. If you changed it for your needs and called it by `CALL construct_query()` then you should see the dynamically generated query (See the `SELECT query` statement). If everything is fine you can uncomment the `CALL exec_stmt(query)` in order to run this constructed query and get the results you want.

**First step:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS exec_stmt;
DELIMITER @@
CREATE PROCEDURE exec_stmt(
    IN stmt_str TEXT
)
proc: BEGIN
    SET @_stmt_str = stmt_str;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @_stmt_str;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END proc @@
DELIMITER ;
```

**Second step:** NOTE: you need to replace the `your_db_name` and the `table1`, `table2`, `table3` parts in order to get the desired column names dynamically with the `ANY_VALUE()` function.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS construct_query;
DELIMITER @@
CREATE PROCEDURE construct_query()
proc: BEGIN

    DECLARE query TEXT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE columns TEXT DEFAULT NULL;

    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('ANY_VALUE(', COLUMN_NAME, ')'))
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db_name' AND TABLE_NAME IN ('table1', 'table2', 'table3')
    ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA, ORDINAL_POSITION INTO columns;

    SET query = CONCAT (
        'SELECT ',
        columns,
        ' FROM orders ',
        'LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses ON orders.addressid = addresses.id WHERE orders.owner = \'admin\' GROUP BY ordersetid ORDER BY thedate DESC'
    );

    SELECT query;
    -- CALL exec_stmt(query);

END proc @@
DELIMITER ;
```

***Then you can call it:***

```
CALL construct_query();
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I thought this would be possible with just a query. I will try your approach and see if it is applicable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really so difficult to include aggregation functions?

```
SELECT ordersetid, MIN(date) as thedate, MIN(name), SUM(price)
FROM orders o LEFT OUTER JOIN
     addresses a
     ON o.addressid = a.id
WHERE o.owner =  'admin'
GROUP BY ordersetid
ORDER BY thedate DESC;
```

Comment: No, it is not for a few fields, What if you have a thousand? or even a hundred or you have a changing schema?

Comment: @fanbondi . . . What is the issue with more fields?  You just write the query or use the database metadata to write the appropriate expressions.

Comment: well if I have 1000 fields that I want to return, do you mean I should put all those fields in the query? Can I do something like SELECT *?. I will just disable the only_full_group_group_by then. probably I am missing something.